# Understanding CSV Formatting : Why Common Tools Deviate from RFC 4180 Standards?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am attempting to parse numerous CSV files (comma-separated, UTF-8 encoding) and have encountered a recurring issue.

Consider a scenario where I have three fields with the values: : `A, "B", C`. According to RFC 4180

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote

Based on this, my understanding is that the correct CSV representation should be `A,"""B""",C` .However, many files generated by various tools are formatted as:  : `"A, ""B"", C"`

This causes CSV parsers (CsvHelper in c# for instance) to interpret such lines as a single field, rather than three separate fields.

Am I missing something here? Why is this seemingly "incorrect" format so prevalently used across different tools?

For discussion, here is a more realistic example:

`"00AA12345,30/11/2023,30/11/2023,01/12/2023,01/12/2023,""BAS"",1 111 000.27,""NRT"",""Test, ok"","""","""","""","""","""""`

I need to read

- field 0: id
- field 1 to 4 : date
- field 5 : date
- field 6 : string
- field 7 and + : string (can contains double quotes)

Comment: If they are 3 separate CSV fields then it should encode as A,""B"",C  or "A",""B"","C". Alphabetic characters naturally having type string and so not needing quotes around them - although some CSV output always puts strings in quotes.  Verbose CSV encoders always put every string literal in quotes. Others take liberties. The most confusing (but also space saving) is using  ,,  to mean ,0.0, (relying on empty cell ==0 Tools expecting MS Office may use \t or space as the delimiter so not really CSV.

Comment: @MartinBrown "A",""B"","C" causes CSV parser to treat the line as a single field. So it seems it should not be encoded in this format.

Comment: Because *real applications* deviate from it, and [did so for 30+ years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#History) before RFC 4180 was created in 2005. This isn't about Office or encoders at all, applications used different variations to handle unexpected or localized strings. Tabs are actually a better choice that commas, but that's what became common in the US in the 1970s. RFC 4180 was created to ensure there's only one correct way to represent the CSV MIME type, not to fix CSV as a format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that real-world applications might deviate from the RFC standards. However, the widespread and consistent nature of these deviations, observed across numerous tools, is quite puzzling to me.

Comment: I explained why that happens. CSV is a low-fidelity, informal file format, not something defined by RFC standards. It's not accurate, which leads to the problems you describe. That's why applications use variations to get over them. There were quadrillions of CSV files before the RFC came out. That RFC was only created to say "When you download a file with the MIME type  `application/csv` expect these things". The *variations* are better at handling problems. For example, using a tab or § as a separator solves almost all problems. But, in 1972, FORTRAN used a Comma

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suppose that, similar to your approach, I still need to preprocess these files to sanitize and bring them into closer alignment with the RFC standard format...

Comment: I suggest then that your CSV parser is broken. "A",""B"","C" is the minimal CSV representation of the record you suggested. Even a brain dead CSV parser should get the first field containing "A" correctly decoded but it might baulk at ""B"" even though that it is a very commonly used construct it is isn't to strict RFC4180 (which was very late in the day - CSV files have been around since the early 1980s - VisiCalc & clones).

Comment: @NicoD Not at all. Just read them using the correct settings in whatever library you use. After all, you have to *read and parse* those files before "sanitizing" them.

Comment: @MartinBrown no, it was Fortran in 1972. Engineers and computer scientists had to type and print data from the start. By Visicalc's time there were a ton of comma separated files already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh I didn't know that. My first encounter with them was on some Z80 CP/M machine ~1980. Fortran was for heavy number crunching back then so I'm a bit surprised the first CSV files weren't written in Cobol.

Comment: @NicoD what's the *actual, exact* string you need to parse? Post it in the question so we can test it. `"A ""B"" C"` is completely custom, not a CSV. There are no commas or tabs and quotes are used inconsistently. Either that's a single cell value, `A "B" C`, or that's a space-separated line containing the exact strings `"A`, `""B""` and `C"`. Or the developer came up with a completely different way of handling values

Comment: @MartinBrown Sorry for misreading your example. I obviously don't have an issue with the format 'A', '"B"', 'C'. My actual concern is with the format "A, ""B"",  C"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I made a mistake in my example and fixed it in my question. My actual concern is with the format "A, ""B"", C". I get double quote at the beginning and end of line.  So the parser treats it like a field.

Comment: `"A, ""B"", C"` are you sure this isn't a single value? Or three values that include those quotes? Applications don't store multiple values in that form, because they won't be able to read them. That's most definitely *not* common.  Or that's a completely custom format used by a single application. Just because something is text doesn't mean it's CSV

Comment: "A, ""B"", C" **is** a valid single record under RFC4180. Which CSV export tool is outputting that when it is attempting to encode A,""B"",C ? I have never seen anything do that. They either skip quotes entirely and use them only when the string being encoded needs quotes to prevent it being misinterpetted as a formula eg. "-1+A" or they put all strings in quotes even when it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: @MartinBrown "A, ""B"", C" is a one field only record. Not three fields. Are you agree with this ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have more than 40 fields (date, decimal, string) so at least it should not be a single value. I receive theses kind of files from two totally different systems. But i agree It seems that the query concatenates the fields and treats them as a single column

Comment: @NicoD post an example of the actual data and its meaning, or at least what you expect this to be. I suspect you oversimplified the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited the question shared a more realistic example

Comment: @NicoD we need to see an actual example of the failing data record(s) verbatim. I can't see any decent CSV encoder using "A..  like that although I think I might have seen one using 'A in the dim and distant past.

Comment: @NicoD The encoding end is broken. It should terminate each distinct quoted string field with  ", . for CSV encoding.  Accepting the record "as is" and then parsing it for a second time using "," as the delimiter will solve your immediate problem.

Comment: @MartinBrown sorry i dont get your point. Can you detail.

Comment: I must add that I have used CSV files and parsers on many occasions. However, it's the frequency and the specifics of this particular use case that have left me puzzled. I even started to think that it might be a specific format for this kind of data

Comment: That looks like the entire line was encoded *twice*, because something tried to "fix" the file. It's as if an application that expected `;` as a separator read a comma-separated file, and then saved it again with a full quote setting. Each line was treated as a single text field and quoted

Comment: @NicoD I'll try again. If you strip the first and last " from the record that you received then it looks to me like a fairly reasonable CSV stream just not to the RFC. The only dodgy looking part is ",1 111 000.27," which looks to be either a malformed floating point number or is using a non comma delimiter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I completely agree, which is why now I remove the first and last double quotes from each line to enable file parsing. Additionally, I have to eliminate the double double quotes surrounding each field, as the parser encounters difficulties when there's a double quote present within a field

Comment: @MartinBrown Yes, I remove the first and last double quotes from each line to facilitate file parsing. I have no problem parsing standard formats like '1 111 000.27' to decimal. However, when a double quote is present within a field, the presence of double double quotes becomes problematic

Comment: I don't understand your problem then. "" is how you escape in a single quote " even in RFC4180 (and "" becomes """" etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CsvMode.Escape` comes close to what you are looking for. It works for your very simple example of `"A, ""B"", C"`.  However, for `""Test, ok""`, it creates two fields `"Test` and `ok"`, which I suspect is supposed to be one field.  But maybe I'm wrong and that does work for you, so I thought I would at least suggest it.

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {
    Mode = CsvMode.Escape   
};
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
```

I tend to agree with @PanagiotisKanavos that this file has been encoded twice. Which is why I would suggest reading it twice. Read it first as if each line is supposed to be a single field and then read that field to get the record.

This removes those double quotes that you say are supposed to be in the field, but I'm not convinced they are supposed to be a part of the data.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("\"00AA12345,30/11/2023,30/11/2023,01/12/2023,01/12/2023");
    sb.Append(",\"\"BAS\"\",1 111 000.27,\"\"NRT\"\",\"\"Test, ok\"\"");
    sb.Append(",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\"\"");
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.Append("\"00AA12345,30/11/2023,30/11/2023,01/12/2023,01/12/2023");
    sb.Append(",\"\"BAS\"\",1 111 000.27,\"\"NRT\"\",\"\"Test, ok\"\"");
    sb.Append(",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\"\"");

    var records = new List<Foo>();

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        while(csv.Read())
        {
            var line = csv.GetRecord<SingleLine>().Line;

            using (var reader2 = new StringReader(line))
            using (var csv2 = new CsvReader(reader2, config))
            {
                if(csv2.Read())
                {
                    var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" } };
                    csv2.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);

                    var record = csv2.GetRecord<Foo>();
                    records.Add(record);
                }               
            }
        }       
    }
    records.Dump();
}

public class SingleLine
{
    public string Line { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string Field0 { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public DateTime Field1 { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public DateTime Field2 { get; set; }
    [Index(3)]
    public DateTime Field3 { get; set; }
    [Index(4)]
    public DateTime Field4 { get; set; }
    [Index(5)]
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
    [Index(6)]
    public string Field6 { get; set; }
    [Index(7)]
    public string Field7 { get; set; }
    [Index(8)]
    public string Field8 { get; set; }
    [Index(9)]
    public string Field9 { get; set; }
    [Index(10)]
    public string Field10 { get; set; }
    [Index(11)]
    public string Field11 { get; set; }
    [Index(12)]
    public string Field12 { get; set; }
    [Index(13)]
    public string Field13 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for detailed suggestion. I checked some of the files and it's definitly a possibility

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a specific code issue, I'll just address this high-level question:

> Why Common Tools Deviate from RFC 4180 Standards?

The answer is this standard wasn't published until 2005, but CSV data has been in use for *FAR LONGER*. For much of the time we've been using CSV data, *there was no standard!* (And we got by just fine, thankyouverymuch).

This means there is not only a **LOT** of non-compliant CSV data still in the wild, but also still a significant number of legacy systems continuing to produce new non-compliant outputs today, and even new applications created to match non-compliant behavior so they function within a larger system (a complete Ship of Theseus of non-compliant CSV).

CSV parsers need to be able to handle this.

Comment: `CSV parsers need to be able to handle this`. I'm not sure I agree with that. That's how you end up with programs like Excel that turn `1-9` into `9-Jan` when I meant `1 to 9`.  But it's not just that, it is more simple things. For instance, in this question's example data, is the field supposed to include double quotes in the data or not. No, if the file includes non-standard RFC 4180 CSV, then you very likely need a very specific parser to handle the specifics of that data format.